# How to get a better dataframe display in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'am taking an online course on data analysis using pandas and numpy.
in course videos when tutors display the dataframe in jupyter notebook, that's what they get:

[what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOLvl.png)

but when i display the dataframe that's what i get:

[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofi5V.png)

i have tried `print(df)` , `display(df)` and just `df` in jupyter notebook and non of them seems to do any change.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear what you are hoping to do. Are you trying to format your table in some way? Could you explain what it is in the first image you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i think it has something to do with html style and css or so

Comment: Jupyter notebook supports HTML formatting (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). I think they were globally changing the table style somewhere